# Unable to connect JupyterHub on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

I have created EMR cluster (5.23.0) with JupyterHub. I create ssh tunnel to 9443 on master node. However, I am not able to connect to JupyterHub, the page does not resolve.Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: Actual problem was quite stupid. It does not work with `http` but works with `https`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your security groups configured correctly. Double check them just to be sure.

As for the JupyterHub, have you checked that the JupyterHub docker container is running?

If you SSH into the master node and run:

```
sudo docker ps
```

You will be given a list of running docker containers. If the list is empty, try starting the container manually:

```
sudo docker start jupyterhub
```

The web interface at port 9443 on your EMR master node should be available.